# Cayley's Theorem question: examples of groups which aren't symmetric groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Basically, Cayley's Theorem says that every finite group, say $G$, is isomorphic to a subgroup of the group $S_G$ of all permutations of $G$.

My question: why is there the word "subgroup of"? If we omit this word, is the statement wrong? brief examples would be nice.

Thank you guys so much!

Comment: If you read the proof you will understand why the subgroup part is necessary.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber:  This is true, but it can be understood much more quickly, as the answers here show.

Comment: Brief examples? You're looking for examples of groups that are not symmetric groups? Try, well, *almost anything*. Any abelian group of order $>2$ for instance.

Answer (score 6):

For example, $D_4 \cong G$ where $G \leq S_4, G\not\cong S_4$.

The group $D_4$ has order $8$, and hence, ***there is no*** $S_n$ such that $|S_n| = n! = 8$. But there is a subgroup of $S_4$ which is isomorphic to $D_4$.

Furthermore, there exists lots of cyclic groups, but for $n > 2$, $S_n$ is NOT cyclic. But there are *subgroups* of $S_n$ that *are* cyclic. The same is true with respect to abelian groups, as DonAntonio points out.

So the theorem would be absurd if the restriction "isomorphic to *a subgroup of* $S_G$" were omitted!

Answer (score 5):

If you take any group of order $n>2$, the number of elements of $S_G$ is $n!$, which is strictly greater than $n$, so there is no way that $G$ can be isomorphic to $S_G$. What this means is that there are permutations of the elements of $G$ that can't be realised simply by multiplying by a group element.

Answer (score 4):

The symmetric group $S_n$ has order $n!$ whereas there exists a group of any order (eg. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has order $n$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ In $\rm\,\langle \Bbb Z/n, +\rangle\,$ if cycle $(0,1)$ is a shift $\rm\:x\to x\!+\!a\:$ then $\rm\: 0\!+\!a\equiv1,\,\ 1\!+\!a\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:1\equiv a\equiv -1.$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the group $\langle \Bbb Z, +\rangle$ of integers under addition.

The Cayley representation of this group contains permutations $P_a$ where $$P_a(n) = n+a.$$  That is, each element of the Cayley representation is a permutation of $\Bbb Z$ obtained by shifting the entire number line rigidly left or right . (Or, in the case of $P_0$, leaving it fixed.)

Clearly, there are many permutations of $\Bbb Z$ that are not of this form.  For example, one such permutation exchanges $17$ and $23$ and leaves all the other integers fixed; this is *not* an element of the Cayley representation of 
$\langle \Bbb Z, +\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes only thing someone needs is a concrete example like this one.